# Understanding one of the active contour algorithm equations

Tags: math, equation, image-segmentation, equation-solving

I'm working with a image segmentation using Active Contour Algorithm. I'm reading book 'Deformable Models: Biomedical and Clinical Applications'. There's is written how to apply this algorithm. I'm stuck because I don't undestant this highlighted part. So why 'l' has only one variable v[i] if function l has summation sign which works with all points but not exactly with v[i] and v[i+1]?

[image]

Comment: L(v(i)) will result in the same value for any i. The summation notation bounds should probably have been written as: *Sum (lowerbound: i=i and upperbound: N-1)*, this is because when i=n, the Yellow formula would require v(n+1) which is kind of strange. Anyway, I am no expert in this field.